# deleting a text on doOnTextChanged deletes the special format of the edit text that I am setting programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, text-formatting

I am trying to format an edit text so when the user types the first two numbers, an `'` is automatically added, then, after the two next numbers types a `.` so the final result looks like this: `12'34'567` The formatting works correctly, except that when the user deletes a character the `'` and `.` get eliminated and the textview changes to `123456`. Is there a way in which I can handle formatting of the edit text in a better way? Here is the code of my formatter:

```
private fun setCoordenatesFormat(editText: EditText){
    editText.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
        
        if(editText.text.length==2){
            editText.setText("${text.toString()}'")
            editText.setSelection(3)
        }
        if(editText.text.length==5){
            editText.setText("${editText.text}.")
            editText.setSelection(6)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best approach but you could try and detect when the user is deleting the textview and with the length of the text you can know in which segment you are and avoid the deleting of your desired format.  You will have to accomplish this with a TextWatcher.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
    
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        if(after<count){
                //got deleted
        }
    }
    
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            //your code on textchanged
    }
})
```

Comment: thankyou very much! I know that this is not the best approach but I will try to use this and get back to you.

Answer (score -1):

The special characters you've inserted disappear because in your conditionals you're checking for specific lengths to format the string. So, for instance, when you check:

```
if(editText.text.length==5){
            editText.setText("${editText.text}.")
            editText.setSelection(6)
        }
```

and then, when you delete last character from EditText, the new string's length should be 4, which isn't equal to 5, nor 2.

Comment: Yes, I`ve come to noticed that. Do you know of a better approach that I can use so this doesn't happen?